# auto redirect all domains to single https domain in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Ok so here's my issue.  I have a bunch of domains pointing to a single server and app.

What I need to do is redirect all domains not set as the $_ENV['site_url'].

here's what I Have so far but it's really ugly and doesn't account for other urls in the app (just global and redirects to the home page).

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $host = Request::server('HTTP_HOST');
    $host = Request::server('HTTPS') == 'on' ? 'https://'.$host : 'http://'.$host;
    if ($host != $_ENV['APP_URL']) {
        return Redirect::to($_ENV['APP_URL']);
    }
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to your Apache (or nginx) server configuration?  I would prefer to keep that kind of logic out of a repository.

Comment: Yes I do, I guess I could put it all in there.  was just wondering if there was a Laravel 4 way of doing it well heh.  If there isn't I go ahead and do it in my nginx config.

Comment: Fair enough, does `Redirect::to($_ENV['APP_URL'] . Request::server('REQUEST_URI'));` work?  Let me know and I can add it as an answer.  The only note is that this will redirect any `POST` requests to a `GET` (which should be fine, as long as you specify the correct URL in all `POST` requests you craft).